# Mysql lampp not running in ubuntu desktop

Tags: server, mysql, xampp

I have a Ubuntu Desktop as server because my IT Manager require Desktop version with lampp from xampp "apachefriends", and yesterday my IT Manager leave the server with no one KB, 0, nothing.

The server give me fail, it's when I notice the no space in hdd.
After remove libreoffice to get space and restart the computer. I try to start lampp with:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

all ok, but my website and phpmyadmin can't connect to mysql

I tried to stop:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop

XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
```

I tried:

```
sudo rm /opt/lampp/var/mysql/pc-name.pid
```

and don't exist

```
ls /opt/lampp/var/mysql/
```

and no one .pid

What can I do?

Comment: Why don't you install and use the LAMP stack that comes with Ubuntu (like Wildfire suggests)?

Comment: I will do it if I can't get xampp working

Answer (score 1):

you can try following these steps: (ofcourse remove anything you have installed earlier)

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install apache2
>   sudo apt-get install php mysql-server php-mysql
>   sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Comment: I will do it if I can't get xampp working

Comment: as you wish to.. jose moran